# my site is coded for responsive site but it is not

Tags: html, image, definitions

I have a definition list with images next to them to use as bullets - but i can not figure out how to align the bullets.  i dont want them choppy and i have tryed to do a list but the image wont work as a bullet that way -

```
 <dl id="list"> 
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png" alt="bullet" align="middle" >Resident     Manager On Site</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Low Montly Rates</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Access 7 Days a Week</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">8 Sizes Available From 5x5 to 10x30</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Free Use of Truck With Move-In</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Controlled Entry and Exit Video Surveilance</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Fenced and Lighted</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Insurance Avaiable</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Comercial and Residential Uses</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Access 365 Days a Year</dd>
    <dd><img src="img/bullet.png">Locally Owned and Operated</dd>
 </dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want an unordered list for this: `<ul> ... <li> list item </li> ... </ul>`

If you want to use the custom bullets, use the following CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('img/bullet.png');
}
```

Comment: I did this but the image is not coming up at all *sad face*

Comment: thanks everyone it all worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use CSS for this. You also don't want to use a description list (<dl>) for this, you want an unordered list (<ul>).

See this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_list.asp for how to setup the CSS to use your bullet.png as the bullet of your lists.